# How to send a response from a module passing them the request and response objects in RESTIFY

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

What I am trying to achieve is to send a response directly from a module instead of sending it from app.js.

for example :

/////app.js/////

```
server.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
/*call a function of mymodule.*/
}
```

/////mymodule.js/////

```
function mymodule(){
/*Send my response from here.*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to acheived is to exposed a function in your `mymodule.js`file.

To do that, you tell to node what you want to **exports** in a file. (You can find documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)).

So to do what you want, you need to export the function *mymodule*. You can do this in this kind of approach :

```
// from mymodule.js
var mymodule = function(req, res){
  res.json({
    users: [
      // ...
    ]
  });
}
module.exports = mymodule;
```

This will expose your function *mymodule* when an other file will required it. So on your app.js, you could use it like this:

```
// from app.js
var required_module = require(__dirname + '/mymodule');
// ...
server.get('/user', function (req, res) {
  required_module(req, res);
});
```

Or an other approch:

```
// from app.js
var required_module = require(__dirname + '/mymodule');
// ...
server.get('/user', required_module);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Swatto.But what i wanted to implement is to send response object from the module itself.As you have mentioned you passed the req,res and next to module function but can you go a step further and explain how can i send response back to client using command res.send() in module.

Comment: I've edited my response with a response made in the module itself.